Problema con las views
estoy haciendo un trabajo para una evaluacion de la universidad y tengo un problema con las view, pues si bien se crean correctamente cuando intento visualizarlas con el select no hay nada es que segun el trabajo tengo que mostrar los proyectos activos junto a los empleados asignados y sus respectivos cargos y pues he intentado varios metodos desde el inner join, el select where,etc y simplemente nada sigue en blanco a continuacion dejo el codigo por si alguien me puede ayudar.
create TABLE Gestion_de_Empleados( 
   id_Empleado NUMBER NOT NULL,
   nombre_empleado varchar(50),
   apellido_empleado varchar(50),
   cargo varchar (100),
   fecha_contratacion date,
   sucursal varchar (90)
);

create table Sucursal(
id_sucursal NUMBER NOT NULL,
nombre_sucursal varchar(50),
direccion varchar(100)
);

create table Gestion_de_Proyectos(
id_proyecto NUMBER NOT NULL,
nombre_proyecto varchar(50),
descripcion_P varchar(500),
fecha_inicio date,
fecha_finalizacion_ES date,
cliente_asociado varchar(30)
);

create table Gestion_de_Clientes(
id_cliente NUMBER NOT NULL,
nombre_empresa varchar(30),
direccion_Clt varchar (100),
numero_telefono int,
nombre_contacto_principal varchar(50)
);

create sequence id_Empleado 
start with 10000 
increment by 1;

create sequence id_proyecto 
start with 2000 
increment by 5;

insert into gestion_de_empleados(id_empleado,nombre_empleado,apellido_empleado,cargo,fecha_contratacion,sucursal)
VALUES (id_empleado.nextval,'lulu','shinjo','contadora','01-03-2001','calle matta, antofagasta')

insert into gestion_de_empleados(id_empleado,nombre_empleado,apellido_empleado,cargo,fecha_contratacion,sucursal)
VALUES (id_empleado.nextval,'marco','rossi','programador','02/11/2004','calle iquique, antofagasta')

insert into gestion_de_empleados(id_empleado,nombre_empleado,apellido_empleado,cargo,fecha_contratacion,sucursal)
VALUES (id_empleado.nextval,'adell','andres','guardia','15/05/2007','calle los condes, antofagasta')

insert into gestion_de_empleados(id_empleado,nombre_empleado,apellido_empleado,cargo,fecha_contratacion,sucursal)
VALUES (id_empleado.nextval,'rin','yuga','programadora','01/01/2011','calle matta, antofagasta')

insert into gestion_de_empleados(id_empleado,nombre_empleado,apellido_empleado,cargo,fecha_contratacion,sucursal)
VALUES (id_empleado.nextval,'paul','lopez','guardia','20/09/2011','calle iquique, antofagasta')

insert into Sucursal(id_sucursal,nombre_sucursal,direccion)
values(1, 'Neo-Antofagasta','calle matta,antofagasta')

insert into Sucursal(id_sucursal,nombre_sucursal,direccion)
values(2, 'Cielo Despejado', 'calle los condes,antofagasta')

insert into Sucursal(id_sucursal,nombre_sucursal,direccion)
values(3, 'playa blanca', 'calle iquique,antofagasta')

insert into gestion_de_clientes(id_cliente,nombre_empresa,direccion_clt,numero_telefono,nombre_contacto_principal)
values(4,'Los Santos', 'calle los groves 158','9891770','Carlos')

insert into gestion_de_clientes(id_cliente,nombre_empresa,direccion_clt,numero_telefono,nombre_contacto_principal)
values(5,'Los Vagos', 'calle almart 202','9741348','Amanda')

insert into gestion_de_clientes(id_cliente,nombre_empresa,direccion_clt,numero_telefono,nombre_contacto_principal)
values(6,'Los Fierros', 'calle piñones','9633135','Laura')

insert into gestion_de_proyectos(id_proyecto,nombre_proyecto,descripcion_P,fecha_inicio,fecha_finalizacion_ES,cliente_asociado)
values(id_proyecto.nextval,'proyecto red de playa','proyecto encargado de reforzar las medidas de seguridad para datos personales','11-08-2002','20-10-2002','Amanda')

insert into gestion_de_proyectos(id_proyecto,nombre_proyecto,descripcion_P,fecha_inicio,fecha_finalizacion_ES,cliente_asociado)
values(id_proyecto.nextval,'proyecto Limpieza de pasillo','proyecto Con el que se busca eliminar virus residuantes en los programas con mas antiguedad','07-01-2001','05-04-2004','Carlos')

insert into gestion_de_proyectos(id_proyecto,nombre_proyecto,descripcion_P,fecha_inicio,fecha_finalizacion_ES,cliente_asociado)
values(id_proyecto.nextval,'proyecto Atencion express','proyecto con el que se busca brindar una atencion mas rapida mediante un programa que notifique de llamadas de clientes mas rapidamente','06-03-2003','24-11-2003','Laura')


select * from gestion_de_empleados
select * from sucursal
select * from gestion_de_proyectos
select * from gestion_de_clientes

alter table gestion_de_empleados
add constraint empleados_pk primary key (id_empleado)

alter table gestion_de_proyectos
add constraint proyecto_pk primary key (id_proyecto)

alter table gestion_de_clientes
add constraint cliente_pk primary key (id_cliente)

alter table sucursal
add constraint sucursal_pk primary key (id_sucursal)

create synonym personal for gestion_de_empleados;
create public synonym empleados for gestion_de_empleados;

create synonym plan for gestion_de_proyectos;
create public synonym plan for gestion_de_proyectos;

create synonym persona for gestion_de_cliente;
create public synonym contacto for gestion_de_cliente;

alter table gestion_de_proyectos
add estado varchar(15);

update plan
set estado = 'activo'
where id_proyecto = 2000;


select * from plan

select * from personal

alter table gestion_de_proyectos
add empleado_asignado varchar(20)

alter table gestion_de_proyectos
add progreso varchar(15) 

select * from plan

update plan
set empleado_asignado = 'marco'
where id_proyecto = 2005;

update plan
set progreso = 'finalizado'
where id_proyecto = 2005;

alter table gestion_de_proyectos
add constraint gestion_de_proyectos_EmpAsign_fk 
foreign key (empleados_id_Empleado)
references gestion_de_empleados(id_empleado)

alter table Sucursal
add constraint empleado_asignadoS_pk

alter table gestion_de_proyectos
add constraint cliente_asignado

select * from plan
select * from personal


create view proyectos_activos as
select id_proyecto,nombre_proyecto,descripcion_p,fecha_inicio,fecha_finalizacion_es,empleado_asignado,cargo
from gestion_de_proyecto, gestion de empleados;

create or replace view proyectos_activos
as select plan.id_proyecto, nombre_proyecto,descripcion_p,fecha_inicio,fecha_finalizacion_es,empleado_asignado,progreso,estado,cargo
from plan
inner join personal
on plan.id_proyecto = personal.id_empleado;

select * from proyectos_activos
where estado = 'activo';


vos estas seguro que esto esta bien???? on plan.id_proyecto = personal.id_empleado;
